# Is there any way to turn displacement of a shader into actual geometry?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, shaders, geometry, displacement

I created a terrain in cycles using displacement and noise texture nodes like this:

[image]

But this is all only applied at render time to a plane. Is there any way to turn this into actual geometry that I could use in a fluid sim as an effector for liquid to flow over? I can't seem to find any answer to this. Would be an awesome way to generate terrain for this.

[image]

Comment: You will have to bake the displacement to a texture, then apply this texture in a displace modifier. Related : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY